# Flutter accessibility header semantic outside page view

Tags: ios, flutter, accessibility, voiceover

I'm trying to get voice over to find all headers in current page but I can't get it to work. It will only find the AppBar title and the header displayed in view.

Example:
When I scroll past the first header the second header will be found, but when I try to navigate back to previous header it jumps to the AppBar title instead of header 1.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Accessibility header'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Semantics(
              header: true,
              child: Text('Header 1'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 1000),
            Semantics(
              header: true,
              child: Text('Header 2'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

I have tried to use "addAutomaticKeepAlives: true" on the ListView and added AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin for widgets inside the list but that only makes the widget stay after they first have been scrolled to. When the user enter the page the first time all headers will not be possible to move to by voice over.